# Is this matrice definition correct in java?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

i was following this code example and i'm new to java but this array definition seems confusing to me this is the link :
https://www.codejava.net/coding/how-to-write-excel-files-in-java-using-apache-poi

[image: array of type objects]

Comment: `bookData` is an array of arrays - ask yourself what is at `bookData[0]` or `bookData[0][1]`.

Comment: It creates a two-dimensional array and fills it with the given objects. The numbers are boxed into Integer's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's simplify it to that:

```
Object[][] data={
    {"A0","B0",0},
    {"A1","B1",1}
}
```

`Object[] a={<content>}` is a short form of `Object[] a=new Object[]{<content>}` but this does only work in the declaration.

It does **not** work like this:

```
Object[] data;
data={};
```

but the following will work:

```
Object[] data={};
```

`Object[][]` means an array of array of objects.

The outer array contains of two(in your case four) arrays: `{"A0","B0",0},` and `{"A1","B1",1},`.

Each inner array consists of 3 objects.

As a String is an `Object` and the numbers are automatically boxed to objects, the inner arrays can easily be created as arrays of objects.

Note that the inner arrays can have different lengths because `Object[][]` just requires arrays of objects and the length does not matter for that.

Also note that every type (in java) implicitely extends object and you can therefor store everything in an `Object`.

Comment: OK thanks, i was just confused because i was expecting the following declaration before : object[ ][ ]  bookDara = new object[ ][ ]

Comment: `Object[] a={<content>}` is a short form of `Object[] a=new Object[]{<content>}`.

Answer (score 1):

It is correct .

for example , Object[][] people = {
{"name1","address","number"},{"name2","address","number"}};

it can contain more arrays as you want and you can make to contin as many as object inside it